# How do I add a setinterval to this getJson

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, setinterval

Hi there I am looking to set a setinterval of 30 seconds to my getJson function any hints would be graciously received ...

My code is as follows ...

```
  $(function() 
{

$(document).ready(function()
 {



    $.getJSON("tempdata.json",function(data)
    {
            $.each(data.recent, function(i,data){
                var div_data ="<div class='row'><div class='col-sm-12   rowpost'><div class='col-sm-3'><div class='postplace'><img src='"+data.coverurl+"' width='80' height='50'></img></div></div><div class='col-sm-9'>  <span class='post_title1'>"+data.trackartist+"</span><br>  <small1><em>"+data.tracktitle+"</em></small1></div></div></div>";

                $(div_data).appendTo("#Tracksinner");
            });
        }
    );
    return false;
});


});
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? Do you want a 30 second pause before requesting the JSON or before appending the div?

Comment: Not sure I understand... You want to make a new request every 30 seconds to fetch the data from the server? In that case, just wrapping the $.getJSON function in window.setInterval should do it.

Comment: I want to do the call every 30 seconds

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to ecapsulate your function to fetch your data on each interval.

To make an intial run you call the function `update_trackdata()` After that the interval will take over.

```
  $(document).ready(function() {

    function update_trackdata() {
            $.getJSON("tempdata.json", function(data) {
                var div_data = "";
                $.each(data.recent, function(i, data) {
                    div_data += "<div class='row'><div class='col-sm-12   rowpost'><div class='col-sm-3'><div class='postplace'><img src='" + data.coverurl + "' width='80' height='50'></img></div></div><div class='col-sm-9'>  <span class='post_title1'>" + data.trackartist + "</span><br>  <small1><em>" + data.tracktitle + "</em></small1></div></div></div>";
                    ("#Tracksinner");
                });
                $("#Tracksinner").html(div_data);
            });
            return false;
    }

    update_trackdata();

    var interval = setInterval(update_trackdata, 30000);

});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but this adds data to end I would like to overwrite the div every time

Comment: Is that just one row? ..  Use `html()` .. I will add some comment.

Comment: tempdata.json has the artist track title and cover image for last 20 songs played

Comment: Thanks for your update but this leaves the area blank on load

Comment: See updates. The interval does kick in after the first 30s, so you will need to do an initial run. I exported the function from the interval.

Comment: Thank you that seems to have done the trick without killing the code answer accepted much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

use setTimeout for wait .....

Try

```
$.getJSON("tempdata.json", function (data) {

    setTimeout(function () {
        $.each(data.recent, function (i, data) {
            var div_data = "<div class='row'><div class='col-sm-12   rowpost'><div class='col-sm-3'><div class='postplace'><img src='" + data.coverurl + "' width='80' height='50'></img></div></div><div class='col-sm-9'>  <span class='post_title1'>" + data.trackartist + "</span><br>  <small1><em>" + data.tracktitle + "</em></small1></div></div></div>";

            $(div_data).appendTo("#Tracksinner");
        });
    }, 30000);

});
```

Comment: does this replace all my original code or get added into document ready function ?

Comment: you only need to use `$(document).ready(function(){//code here});`.

Comment: ah i just noticed this is to wait 30 seconds I need to redo the function every 30 seconds and overwrite the original data

Comment: This would run once and not repeatedly on an interval.

Comment: You need to be repetitive??

Comment: yes I need it to load with the page and then update every 30 seconds after this thanks

Answer (score 1):

```js
var timer;

timer = setInterval(function() {

  // Your get JSON call

}, 30 * 1000);
```